# How can I find the prototypes for the following functions and Structure

Tags: windows, assembly, struct, system-calls, function-prototypes

**-- NTDLL.DLL --**

Functions:
NtPssCaptureVaSpaceBulk, NtAllocateUserPhysicalPagesEx, NtAcquireCrossVmMutant, NtCreateCrossVmMutant, NtDirectGraphicsCall, NtWriteErrorLogEntry, NtCreateWinStation, NtOpenWinStation, NtSetWinStationInformation, NtQueryWinStationInformation

Structure:
CHANNEL_MESSAGE

Comment: You'd probably need access to the Windows source. For some of them you'd need access really the really old Windows NT Terminal Server edition source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I know almost of them are supported in Windows 10 (2004, 20H2). Kindly check the following link. https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/

Comment: Kindly check the link you gave yourself.  If you had bothered to do this, you'd have noticed that none of the "WinStation" system calls you've given are listed there.  That's because they're not implemented in any 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: I will share the following screenshort. It is a screen of Ntdll.dll diassembly. This Ntdll.dll is a file of Windows 10 I currently use. I am sure these functions was implemented newly and have no document yet. Please help me to find any info for those functions. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SKBROl6qWio43baXuZ-84MePKVN28u73/view