# Find the prototypes of some Windows Kernel APIs like NtAllocateUserPhysicalPagesEx

Tags: c++, system-calls, windows-kernel, ntdll

I can't find the prototypes of some modern Windows kernel APIs and a structure. I am pretty sure these functions are defined in ntdll.dll because they can be seen in the export tables of it, but I can't see any documents for them. Even there are no any information in winsdk-10/ntifs.h.
Here are the list of missing functions and a structure that I am looking for.

**Functions:**

*NtPssCaptureVaSpaceBulk, NtAllocateUserPhysicalPagesEx, NtAcquireCrossVmMutant, NtCreateCrossVmMutant, NtDirectGraphicsCall, NtWriteErrorLogEntry, NtCreateWinStation, NtOpenWinStation, NtSetWinStationInformation, NtQueryWinStationInformation*

**Structure:**

*CHANNEL_MESSAGE*

If you have any information for them, help me to share them kindly. Thank you.

Comment: Not everything exported from ntdll.dll is actually part of the documented API. Technically you are only supposed to use functions that are actually documented even if they are declared in the SDK headers, but there are functions that don't even have that much and are simply exported for internal use.

Comment: Please do not repost the same question [How can I find the prototypes for the following functions and Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65671268/how-can-i-find-the-prototypes-for-the-following-functions-and-structure). If you need to add something, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65671268/edit) the original question, instead.